# Add new data center to Cassandra with replication factor of 1

Tags: cassandra

I want to add a backup data center on a cloud provider. Assume I have DC1, DC2, DC3 in the cluster and I want DC4 have every piece of data in the cluster with replication of 1. Is this achievable using `nodetool rebuild`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no issues adding a new DC with just one replica and you should be able to populate it with data using `nodetool rebuild`.

However, simply running backups of this new DC is not technically a "full backup" unless you have made sure that all keyspaces are replicated to this new DC. The only exceptions are `system` and `system_schema` keyspaces which are configured with `LocalStrategy` only since they are not designed to be replicated to other DCs. Cheers!

Comment: How to make sure that the keyspaces are fully replicated to the new DC? Also, for new data in the old DC, would `nodetool rebuild` captures that data?

Comment: I'm cautious about answering your follow up questions in the comments section because it could end up being a never-ending thread. The general advice is to only ask one question per post so I suggest opening a new one. Cheers!